# C Use specific ip address and port for Udp socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I want to use specific UDP port for socket, I used the following code

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Bind to a specific network address and port 
struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.100");
localaddr.sin_port = htons(7547);  // Any local port will do
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));
```

But when I capture trafic using Wireshark, I see that the used source port is different from setted value (random port).

Comment: What does the call to `bind()` return? It might have failed?

Comment: Did bind() work? `On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.`

Comment: ***Is*** `192.168.1.100` the address of an active ***local*** interface?

Comment: the bind failed

Comment: but even if I set socket option to reuse address and port, the bind failed

Comment: In case `bind()` returns `-1` immediately call `perror()` and learn *why* it failed.